# Using CMB2 Plugin to create text_date metabox (datepicker) How do I save multiple dates?

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I currently have a metabox with a custom date field but I'm wondering how do I customize it to save multiple dates instead of just one? (I need it to function similar to the tags metabox)?

Answer (score 1):

In **CMB2** you can use the `group` type to create a repeating fields, then inside the group, you declare the `text_date` type.

Let's say you have an **Events** where you set multiple dates.

```
$events = new_cmb2_box([
    'id' => 'events_metabox',
    'title' => __('Events', 'text_domain'),
    'object_types' => ...,
    'show_on' => ...,
    ...
]);

$events_group_id = $events->add_field([
    'id' => 'events',
    'type' => 'group',
    'desc' => ...,
    'options' => [
        'group_title' => __('Event Date {#}', 'text_domain'),
        'add_button' => __('New Event Date', 'text_domain'),
        'remove_button' => __('Remove Event Date', 'text_domain')
    ]
]);

$events->add_group_field($events_group_id, [
    'id' => 'event_text_date',
    'name' => __('Event Date', 'text_domain'),
    'desc' => ...,
    'type' => 'text_date'
]);
```

Comment: This works, except instead of adding a new box each time, I want it to just add the data. How do I do that? Say my user wants to add 500 dates to their post...that's going to end up being a lot of metaboxes.

Comment: That's the only possible way in **CMB2**, if you want the same functionality like **tags** the only workaround is custom code your metabox.